# Forward contracts

Tags: finance, economics

[image]

How do I do this one? I'm assuming it's not as simple as "the initial value is just $50 since thats what the stock sells at"

Comment: Is this from chapter 5 of Hull? Determination of forward and future prices.

Comment: @Alan nope, but it is chapter five in the book i'mm using!

Answer (score 1):

You basically buy the stock without the intervening dividends 6 months from now. Subtract from the current value of 50 the present values of the dividends, to get the 'naked' current value, then compute the future value of that 5 months from now. The other possible gotcha is the way you transform the risk free rate - but for a problem it's probably just given in the exponential form.

Comment: so just assume we have one stock for convenience, then at 2 months the value is 49, then 5 months 48.  this is the naked value as you've said. 

then, the future value of this 5 months from now will be:

$48e^{0.04*\frac{5}{12}} \approx 48.806$

This gives us the forward price, correct?

What about the initial value?

Comment: no, you forgot to time-propagate it forward to just before the dividend pay time before subtracting the dividend (something like $50 \to 50e^{0.04\frac{2}{12}} \to 50e^{0.04\frac{2}{12}} - 1 \to \ldots$ . That's why it's easier to just time value back the dividends: $(50 - 1\times e^{-0.04\frac{2}{12}} - 1\times e^{-0.04\frac{5}{12}})\times e^{0.04\frac{6}{12}}$

Comment: seems like I never understand which formula to use..

and also, oops. I didn't realize the length of the investor's short position was 6 months; i thought it was five months.

can you explain what exactly your calculation means? I feel like if I can understand that, I can work through something like this myself easily.

For whatever reason, I'm really bad at applied math, but really good at abstract math, it feels kind of silly.

Comment: It helps if you think of the current stock price as the present value of an infinite stream of dividends (an annuity). The forward contract will be missing the first 2 dividends, so its present value will be the current value minus the present value of those 2. Then the forward price is the expected price 6 mo. from now, so you propagate it forward using the risk free rate as usual. Now, the current value of the forward is zero, as the forward price is equal to the expected stock price (no arbitrage in the initial contract)

Comment: thank you. so in your formula, everything inside the parenthesis is what you called the "naked value" , it's -(1*e . .) since it's a dividend of 1 each time. that makes sense now, thank you.

The initial value of this contract will be the same calculation, but just $50e^{0.04\frac{1}{2}}$ since we didn't subtract the dividend payments, correct?

Comment: what's the initial value?